# Weissinger equation solution in Modelica

Tags: equation, modelica, openmodelica

I wanted to solve the Weissinger equation by Modelica, I tried all existing solvers in OpenModelica, but it failed. has someone tried it?

below is the codes

```
model Weissinger_Equation
  Real y(start = sqrt(3 / 2));
  Real t = time;
  Real yp(start = 0);
equation
  der(y) = yp;
  t * y ^ 2 * yp ^ 3 - y ^ 3 * yp ^ 2 + t * (t ^ 2 + 1) * yp - t ^ 2 * y = 0;
  annotation(
    experiment(StartTime = 0, StopTime = 10, Tolerance = 0.0001, Interval = 0.0002),
    __OpenModelica_commandLineOptions = "--matchingAlgorithm=PFPlusExt --indexReductionMethod=dynamicStateSelection -d=initialization,NLSanalyticJacobian,newInst",
    __OpenModelica_simulationFlags(lv = "LOG_STATS", s = "dassl"));
end Weissinger_Equation;
```

Comment: Isn't the problem rather that you need to solve for yp, but at t=0, the equation is `0.0 = 0.0`? From what I can find, startTime=1.0 should be used to solve this equation and you might have more luck with that.

Comment: Yes could be. From the language specification guide,  the declaration equation Real t = time; is a binding equation and valid throughout the whole simulation.

Answer (score 4):

This works in Dymola.

```
model Weissinger_Equation
  Real y(fixed = true, start = sqrt(3 / 2));
  Real t = time;
  Real yp(start = 0);
equation 
  der(y) = yp;
  t * y ^ 2 * yp ^ 3 - y ^ 3 * yp ^ 2 + t * (t ^ 2 + 1) * yp - t ^ 2 * y = 0;
  annotation (
    experiment(StartTime = 1, StopTime = 10, Tolerance = 0.0001, Interval = 0.0002),
    __OpenModelica_commandLineOptions = "--matchingAlgorithm=PFPlusExt --indexReductionMethod=dynamicStateSelection -d=initialization,NLSanalyticJacobian,newInst",
    __OpenModelica_simulationFlags(lv = "LOG_STATS", s = "dassl"));
end Weissinger_Equation;
```

Comment: I don't know the origin of this equation. But in the specific form written it seems to be copied from Matlab that also simulate from 1 to 10 seconds.

Comment: I believe the reason you cannot find the solution from t=0 is that the equations don't fulfil suitable Lipschitz conditions; and thus any solution close to y0 at t=0 will explode in finite time. (Obviously the function looks smooth - I assume it was constructed to show how to formulate such conditions for implicit odes.) The analytic solution is, of course, y=sqrt(t^2+0.5)

Comment: I have written the equation in Modelica.  the problem is inconsistency of initial condition. if we set the start time=1s to 10 s, it works. there is a commend in matlab for removing the inconsistency (https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/decic.html).